# How can i implement or loop through these blog post layout same way in django template?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

[please take a look at this image i want to show my posts in django like this template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orl5z.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIhUV.png)i got a beginning level problem, actually i found a free template , and i'm trying to do the backend for that template, but i don't know how i can show post lists same as the template in djnago, basically i'm trying to say that how can i implement or loop through and show my posts same as it is shown in template. i just want to show my posts same as template and how to loop through and show same as template, how can i do that?

****I've added an image so you can better understand my problem! ****

```
[<section class="blog_area p_120">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="blog_left_sidebar">
                    <article class="blog_style1">
                        <div class="blog_img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/home-blog/blog-1.jpg' %}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog_text">
                            <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                <div class="cat">
                                    <a class="cat_btn" href="#">Gadgets</a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> March 14, 2018</a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05</a>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <h4>Nest Protect: 2nd Gen Smoke + CO Alarm</h4>
                                </a>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>
                                <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="blog_style1 small">
                                <div class="blog_img">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/home-blog/blog-small-1.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_text">
                                    <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                        <div class="cat">
                                            <a class="cat_btn" href="#">Gadgets</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> March 14, 2018</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="single-blog.html">
                                            <h4>Nest Protect 2nd Gen Smoke CO Alarm</h4>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                        <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="blog_style1 small">
                                <div class="blog_img">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/home-blog/blog-small-2.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_text">
                                    <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                        <div class="cat">
                                            <a class="cat_btn" href="#">Gadgets</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> March 14, 2018</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="single-blog.html">
                                            <h4>Nest Protect 2nd Gen Smoke CO Alarm</h4>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                        <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <article class="blog_style1">
                        <div class="blog_img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/home-blog/blog-2.jpg' %}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog_text">
                            <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                <div class="cat">
                                    <a class="cat_btn" href="#">Gadgets</a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> March 14, 2018</a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05</a>
                                </div>
                                <a href="single-blog.html">
                                    <h4>Nest Protect: 2nd Gen Smoke CO Alarm</h4>
                                </a>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>
                                <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="blog_style1 small">
                                <div class="blog_img">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/home-blog/blog-small-3.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_text">
                                    <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                        <div class="cat">
                                            <a class="cat_btn" href="#">Gadgets</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> March 14, 2018</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="single-blog.html">
                                            <h4>Nest Protect 2nd Gen Smoke CO Alarm</h4>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                        <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="blog_style1 small">
                                <div class="blog_img">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/home-blog/blog-small-4.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_text">
                                    <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                        <div class="cat">
                                            <a class="cat_btn" href="#">Gadgets</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> March 14, 2018</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="single-blog.html">
                                            <h4>Nest Protect 2nd Gen Smoke CO Alarm</h4>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                        <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="blog_style1 small">
                                <div class="blog_img">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/home-blog/blog-small-5.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_text">
                                    <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                        <div class="cat">
                                            <a class="cat_btn" href="#">Gadgets</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> March 14, 2018</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="single-blog.html">
                                            <h4>Nest Protect 2nd Gen Smoke CO Alarm</h4>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                        <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <article class="blog_style1 small">
                                <div class="blog_img">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'img/home-blog/blog-small-6.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_text">
                                    <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                        <div class="cat">
                                            <a class="cat_btn" href="#">Gadgets</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> March 14, 2018</a>
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="single-blog.html">
                                            <h4>Nest Protect 2nd Gen Smoke CO Alarm</h4>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                        <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically when you iterate through your posts, you want to display different html based on iteration counter. You can use django's built-in filters **add** and **divisibleby** for that. For example:

```
{% for post in posts %}
{% if forloop.counter|add:"2"|divisibleby:"3" %}
<article class="blog_style1">
.........
</article>

{% else %}
<article class="blog_style1 small">
.........
</article>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you it's worked :)

but still there's a problem, first row displaying big posts , but in 2nd row there's should be 2 posts but displaying only 1 post then again 1 post, then again displaying big posts..and so on...but i want something like after big posts next row should contain 2 posts, then again big post then again each row should contain 2 posts, i've tried to do but didn't get any solution, will you please explain a bit how can i show 2 posts in each row.